# simulator for Ubuntu phone

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

Is there a simulator for Ubuntu phone?

And if so:

Is there a tutorial using showing how to?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/259338/109543 - they are in the process of working on an emulator, but there is no official time-frame yet.