# Is there an Ubuntu Touch emulator or a way to install it in a VM?

Tags: virtualization, ubuntu-touch, emulation

Is there any way to install Ubuntu Touch inside a virtual machine on a regular Ubuntu computer instead of on a phone or tablet? Or is there an emulator, like the one the Android SDK comes with?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally, there is an emulator!

## Using the Emulator

**How to install on Ubuntu 14.04:**

```
sudo apt-get install android-emulator
cp -r /usr/share/android/emulator/ ~/
cd ~/emulator/
./build-emulator-sdcard.sh
```

**To run the emulator:**

```
./run-emulator.sh
```

For **Ubuntu 13.10 and older**, you should just be able to install the deb from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/android.

**To update your emulator, run these commands:**

```
cd ~/emulator/
rm -f ./out/target/product/generic/ubuntu-rootfs.tar.xz
./build-emulator-sdcard.sh
```

***WARNING:** Do not uninstall and then use `apt-get autoremove` on amd64. If you do, you will be left in an unbeatable state. Follow the instructions [on the wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Emulator) to fix you system.*

For more details or how to build from source, see [the wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Emulator).

## Other Methods

However, using the emulator can be to complex if you just want to run a an app or test the unity8 shell. So, there are two other methods:

### 1. Running Ubuntu Touch Apps

You can now install the core touch applications directly on an computer running Ubuntu 12.10 or later (or one of the derivatives, such as Kubuntu) using a PPA.

First, add the Core Apps Daily PPA by running these commands in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-touch-coreapps-drivers/daily
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install the apps you want by running:

```
sudo apt-get install <app-name>
```

Or you can install all of them using

```
sudo apt-get install touch-coreapps
```

Here is a list of the core apps available:

- ubuntu-calculator-app
- calendar-app
- ubuntu-clock-app
- ubuntu-weather-app
- ubuntu-docviewer-app
- ubuntu-emailclient-app (not working yet)
- ubuntu-filemanager-app
- ubuntu-rssreader-app
- ubuntu-terminal-app
- stock-ticker-mobile-app
- dropping-letters
- sudoku-app
- music-app

For more information, see [this article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/how-to-play-with-ubuntu-touch-apps-in-ubuntu-12-10) on http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/.

### 2. Running the Unity 8 Shell

It is possible to run the mobile interface for Unity 8 on the desktop if you're running Ubuntu 13.10. To do this, install the unity8 package, either by clicking on the link or by typing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install unity8
```

To run it, use this command:

```
unity8 -mousetouch
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to run apps in the shell. Clicking on a desktop app will open it in its own window and clicking on a Ubuntu Touch app will do nothing.

Comment: An emulator is now available.

Comment: See also (for 13.10): http://askubuntu.com/questions/387884/how-to-install-ubuntu-touch-emulator-on-13-10

Answer (score 8):

There's now an experimental Emulator available.
Check out https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Emulator

Comment: This is rather a short answer with just a link. Could you update your answer with screenshots and instructions to install, in case the link gets changed?

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/usr/share/android/emulator/build/tools/get-tarball-url.py`

Change

```
host_uri = "https://system-image.ubuntu.com"
json_index_uri = "/devel-proposed/mako/index.json"
```

to

```
host_uri = "https://system-image.ubuntu.com"
json_index_uri = "/ubuntu-touch/devel-proposed/mako/index.json"
```