# Qt for Ubuntu SDK: Do I need a device or is there a simulator?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

just wondering if the Ubuntu SDK comes with a simulator like Eclipse for Android or if I need to flash an actual device? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/259338/109543). There is no emulator yet, but it should be available soon.

Just in case it's not clear: You can actually run the apps on your pc as well so for the first tests you wouldn't need a simulator or push the app onto the real device. Of course there might be differences with hardware, display, resolution, etc. But for the start it should be sufficient.