# Is there any way to run Ubuntu Touch 1.0 in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-touch

I would love to try out Ubuntu Touch on my Ubuntu 13.10 Desktop. Any way to do this?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/259338/67335