# How to install Ubuntu Touch Emulator on 13.10?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, software-installation

I went through this site [Touch/Emulator - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Emulator) but I'm still not sure how to install Ubuntu Touch Emulator on 13.10. The site pointed me to: [“android” package : Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/android), for downloading a .deb package but I wasn't sure which package to download. I need clear instruction on how to install the ubuntu touch emulator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Dependencies

Install the dependencies with the following PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-emulator
```

---

### Install

To install the Ubuntu Touch x86 Emulator, paste the following in your terminal:

```
wget http://people.canonical.com/~rsalveti/aosp/generic_x86/emulator-x86.tar.bz2 -O /tmp/emulator-x86.tar.bz2
tar -jxvf /tmp/emulator-x86.tar.bz2
cd emulator-x86
./build-emulator-sdcard.sh #this will download the ubuntu rootfs and create the sdcard image
```

To run the emulator:

```
cd emulator-x86; ./run-emulator.sh
```

---

### Scale down the window

If the emulator window doesn't fit in your screen, the you can resize it, by going In the `~/emulator-x86` folder, edit the `run-emulator.sh` file, and add in `-scale 0.5`. To scale it down half the size.

```
 ...
 exec emulator -memory 512 \
    -scale 0.5 \
 ...
```

Source:

- [Ubuntu Touch Emulator: Installation And Usage In Ubuntu 14.04, 13.10 And 12.04 ~ Web Upd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/ubuntu-touch-x86-emulator-better.html)
- [Ubuntu Touch X86 Emulator: Better Emulator Performance, Faster Startup ~ Web Upd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/ubuntu-touch-emulator-installation-and.html)

Comment: **UPDATE** Author of **WebUpd8.org** article has since added: "*for faster startup and better .. overall performance, try .. x86 Emulator preview.*" http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/ubuntu-touch-x86-emulator-better.html

Comment: @david6, thanks! been meaning to update this, but I kept forgetting.

Answer (score 2):

You are using ubuntu 13.10 (saucy salamander) so download [*this*](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/android_20131006-1510-0ubuntu6_all.deb) .deb package.

After that open the terminal<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.Go into the directory where .deb package is downloaded.

```
cd /path/to/the/directory/where/android.deb/file/is/located
sudo dpkg -i android_20131006-1510-0ubuntu6_all.deb
```

Now the emulator will be installed and you can use it.

Comment: Is it the same package for all versions below 14.04 or is it only for 13.10?

Comment: the .deb file link i posted is only for ubuntu 13.10

Comment: I downloaded and installed the package but I'm unable to launch the emulator or locate the emulator directory.